# AWS Rekognition for end-users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-rekognition

I have successfully got AWS Rekognition working with Unauthenticated Identities, i.e. no matter how many different phones on which I run the app, I can only see the same collections, same facial information.

I want each of my users to have different/separated collections. How can I set that up, starting from Identity pool, IAM roles, ...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use authenticated access?

Comment: @NinadGaikwad: Thanks for your quick reply. I have tried to implement authenticated access as you suggested for the past 2 days and learnt that after I get `Token` and `IdentityId`, the collections/faces that I got from AWS are the same although I request on different user. Do you have any ideas about this? Please refer to this question for my setup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372117/cognitoidentityclient-404-not-found-in-iam-security-credentials/57372330#57372330